# Call function onclick on option in select tag?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am making web page there is select tag in page there are options in select tag. I want to call some function of JavaScript on click option.

Comment: Yes, JavaScript for web pages? Crazy! Always use C++ or FALSE... T_T

Answer (score 0):

Welcome at stackoverflow, the side where we love to see a little bit of your source code to provide even better answers to you. :)
Anyway I assume your select tag has an id `selector` and you want to call the method `doSomeStuff` so you can use this:

```
document.getElementById("selector").addEventListener("click", doSomeStuff, false );
```

For further reading about adding EventListeners I recommend you the [MDN pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.addEventListener).